# add column values of two tables that have the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

for example, I have 2 tables

**resto1**

*day 1* = 1 2 3 4

**resto2**

*day 1* = 5 6 7 8

I wanted to add the values of the first two columns that have the same date the result would be:

**day_1_earned** = 6 8 10 12

please help

Comment: Please provide [mcve].  It do not have "same date" in your sample data, and we don't know the relationship between 2 tables too.

Comment: please tell structure of table and references in table.

Answer (score 0):

assuming both the tables have a date column, let say named **dt_col** you can use below query to achieve the required result

```
select t1.column1+t2.column2 added_values from
table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.dt_col = t2.dt_col;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.Column1 + T2.Column As TotalColumn 
From T1, T2 WHERE T1.Date= T2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Cr_date, SUM(Column1) Column1, SUM(Column2) Column2
FROM
(
SELECT Cr_Date,Column1,Column2 FROM #T1
UNION
SELECT Cr_Date,Column1,Column2 FROM #T2
) as res
GROUP BY Cr_Date